# Hive mixes some column values while inserting a large amount of data into a table

Tags: hive, mapreduce, hdfs, hiveql

I have a hive table called 'xtr_iwm_registration' which includes 52 columns and more than 380000 rows. One of its columns called 'transactionid' doesn't have any NULL values. I made a copy of this table using the following statement:

```
`CREATE TABLE xtr_iwm_registration_copy AS SELECT * FROM 
 xtr_iwm_registration;`
```

After that I realized that column 'transactionid' in the new table contains  1311 NULL values although the total number of rows was the same as in the original table. Another column called 'datasource' has only one distinct value in the original table but in the new table it has 76 distinct values and it seems that 75 of them were taken from other columns. I have discovered that hive corrupts data in such way only with pretty large amounts of data (about 90000 rows and higher): with 85000 rows everything was OK, but with 90000 rows I got 26 NULL values in 'transactionid'. I also tried to set map/reduce memory up to 8GB and split my query into 2 parts but it didn't help me:

```
`SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb=8192;
 SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=8192;
 CREATE TABLE xtr_iwm_registration_copy AS SELECT * FROM 
 xtr_iwm_registration LIMIT 0;
 INSERT INTO TABLE xtr_iwm_registration_copy SELECT * FROM 
 xtr_iwm_registration;`
```

In addition there are no errors in the hive log. I use hive version 3.1.1. Has anyone else faced this issue?

**Upd:** resolved this issue by specifying full list of columns (SELECT * FROM... works incorrectly with large amounts of data):

```
`SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb=1024;
 SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=1024;
 CREATE TABLE xtr_iwm_registration_copy LIKE xtr_iwm_registration;
 INSERT INTO xtr_iwm_registration_copy (<list of columns separated by 
 comma>) SELECT <list of columns separated by comma> FROM 
 xtr_iwm_registration;`
```

Comment: you may want to add your source table definition